# navigator.language list of all languages

Tags: javascript

Where i can see the list of languages and their codes?

I want to compare languages and auto-select required language in template.

Are they cross-browser equal?

Any other solution?

Comment: FYI: `navigator.language` for Firefox: http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/Navigator.cpp#l337 (quite straightforward to read), Chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/page/Navigator.cpp&l=89 (follow the tracks of `defaultLanguage` to `Language.cpp` and continue reading)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This list of **languages** is defined by the ISO : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Example : `be` for belarus, `fr` for french.

If you are looking for something more specific, those are not languages, but **locale**, e.g. "Brazilian Portuguese", or "Canadian French". Those can be found in the ICU project: https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/

Example : `pt_BR` for Portuguese (Brazil) vs `pt_CV` for Portuguese (Cape Verde)

Those are the ones available for copy/pasting in dYale answer.

Comment: So it's 639-1 column? Is it's the same in all browsers?

Comment: I guess yes, tho I can't 100% certify it.

Comment: I would say the 639-1 column is the one Javascript uses. I asked a few people in other countries to alert out their code and it matched the values in 639-1.

Comment: this does not answers fully, in the link provided one can find language codes, but not country-specific language codes, like fr-fr or fr-ca

Comment: That is wrong. Mine is pt-BR and is not listed there.

Comment: @LucasBustamante pt_BR is a locale, not a language. pt is the language of the pt_BR locale. See https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/ where they separate those two concepts. I edited my answer to add those :)

Comment: @Clement Herreman thanks for clarifying, I'll check out these two concepts

Answer (score 74):

For copy and pasting purposes:

```js
["af", "af-NA", "af-ZA", "agq", "agq-CM", "ak", "ak-GH", "am",
"am-ET", "ar", "ar-001", "ar-AE", "ar-BH", "ar-DJ", "ar-DZ",
"ar-EG", "ar-EH", "ar-ER", "ar-IL", "ar-IQ", "ar-JO", "ar-KM",
"ar-KW", "ar-LB", "ar-LY", "ar-MA", "ar-MR", "ar-OM", "ar-PS",
"ar-QA", "ar-SA", "ar-SD", "ar-SO", "ar-SS", "ar-SY", "ar-TD",
"ar-TN", "ar-YE", "as", "as-IN", "asa", "asa-TZ", "ast", "ast-ES",
"az", "az-Cyrl", "az-Cyrl-AZ", "az-Latn", "az-Latn-AZ", "bas",
"bas-CM", "be", "be-BY", "bem", "bem-ZM", "bez", "bez-TZ", "bg",
"bg-BG", "bm", "bm-ML", "bn", "bn-BD", "bn-IN", "bo", "bo-CN",
"bo-IN", "br", "br-FR", "brx", "brx-IN", "bs", "bs-Cyrl",
"bs-Cyrl-BA", "bs-Latn", "bs-Latn-BA", "ca", "ca-AD", "ca-ES",
"ca-FR", "ca-IT", "ccp", "ccp-BD", "ccp-IN", "ce", "ce-RU", "cgg",
"cgg-UG", "chr", "chr-US", "ckb", "ckb-IQ", "ckb-IR", "cs",
"cs-CZ", "cy", "cy-GB", "da", "da-DK", "da-GL", "dav", "dav-KE",
"de", "de-AT", "de-BE", "de-CH", "de-DE", "de-IT", "de-LI",
"de-LU", "dje", "dje-NE", "dsb", "dsb-DE", "dua", "dua-CM", "dyo",
"dyo-SN", "dz", "dz-BT", "ebu", "ebu-KE", "ee", "ee-GH", "ee-TG",
"el", "el-CY", "el-GR", "en", "en-001", "en-150", "en-AG",
"en-AI", "en-AS", "en-AT", "en-AU", "en-BB", "en-BE", "en-BI",
"en-BM", "en-BS", "en-BW", "en-BZ", "en-CA", "en-CC", "en-CH",
"en-CK", "en-CM", "en-CX", "en-CY", "en-DE", "en-DG", "en-DK",
"en-DM", "en-ER", "en-FI", "en-FJ", "en-FK", "en-FM", "en-GB",
"en-GD", "en-GG", "en-GH", "en-GI", "en-GM", "en-GU", "en-GY",
"en-HK", "en-IE", "en-IL", "en-IM", "en-IN", "en-IO", "en-JE",
"en-JM", "en-KE", "en-KI", "en-KN", "en-KY", "en-LC", "en-LR",
"en-LS", "en-MG", "en-MH", "en-MO", "en-MP", "en-MS", "en-MT",
"en-MU", "en-MW", "en-MY", "en-NA", "en-NF", "en-NG", "en-NL",
"en-NR", "en-NU", "en-NZ", "en-PG", "en-PH", "en-PK", "en-PN",
"en-PR", "en-PW", "en-RW", "en-SB", "en-SC", "en-SD", "en-SE",
"en-SG", "en-SH", "en-SI", "en-SL", "en-SS", "en-SX", "en-SZ",
"en-TC", "en-TK", "en-TO", "en-TT", "en-TV", "en-TZ", "en-UG",
"en-UM", "en-US", "en-US-POSIX", "en-VC", "en-VG", "en-VI",
"en-VU", "en-WS", "en-ZA", "en-ZM", "en-ZW", "eo", "es", "es-419",
"es-AR", "es-BO", "es-BR", "es-BZ", "es-CL", "es-CO", "es-CR",
"es-CU", "es-DO", "es-EA", "es-EC", "es-ES", "es-GQ", "es-GT",
"es-HN", "es-IC", "es-MX", "es-NI", "es-PA", "es-PE", "es-PH",
"es-PR", "es-PY", "es-SV", "es-US", "es-UY", "es-VE", "et",
"et-EE", "eu", "eu-ES", "ewo", "ewo-CM", "fa", "fa-AF", "fa-IR",
"ff", "ff-CM", "ff-GN", "ff-MR", "ff-SN", "fi", "fi-FI", "fil",
"fil-PH", "fo", "fo-DK", "fo-FO", "fr", "fr-BE", "fr-BF", "fr-BI",
"fr-BJ", "fr-BL", "fr-CA", "fr-CD", "fr-CF", "fr-CG", "fr-CH",
"fr-CI", "fr-CM", "fr-DJ", "fr-DZ", "fr-FR", "fr-GA", "fr-GF",
"fr-GN", "fr-GP", "fr-GQ", "fr-HT", "fr-KM", "fr-LU", "fr-MA",
"fr-MC", "fr-MF", "fr-MG", "fr-ML", "fr-MQ", "fr-MR", "fr-MU",
"fr-NC", "fr-NE", "fr-PF", "fr-PM", "fr-RE", "fr-RW", "fr-SC",
"fr-SN", "fr-SY", "fr-TD", "fr-TG", "fr-TN", "fr-VU", "fr-WF",
"fr-YT", "fur", "fur-IT", "fy", "fy-NL", "ga", "ga-IE", "gd",
"gd-GB", "gl", "gl-ES", "gsw", "gsw-CH", "gsw-FR", "gsw-LI", "gu",
"gu-IN", "guz", "guz-KE", "gv", "gv-IM", "ha", "ha-GH", "ha-NE",
"ha-NG", "haw", "haw-US", "he", "he-IL", "hi", "hi-IN", "hr",
"hr-BA", "hr-HR", "hsb", "hsb-DE", "hu", "hu-HU", "hy", "hy-AM",
"id", "id-ID", "ig", "ig-NG", "ii", "ii-CN", "is", "is-IS", "it",
"it-CH", "it-IT", "it-SM", "it-VA", "ja", "ja-JP", "jgo",
"jgo-CM", "jmc", "jmc-TZ", "ka", "ka-GE", "kab", "kab-DZ", "kam",
"kam-KE", "kde", "kde-TZ", "kea", "kea-CV", "khq", "khq-ML", "ki",
"ki-KE", "kk", "kk-KZ", "kkj", "kkj-CM", "kl", "kl-GL", "kln",
"kln-KE", "km", "km-KH", "kn", "kn-IN", "ko", "ko-KP", "ko-KR",
"kok", "kok-IN", "ks", "ks-IN", "ksb", "ksb-TZ", "ksf", "ksf-CM",
"ksh", "ksh-DE", "kw", "kw-GB", "ky", "ky-KG", "lag", "lag-TZ",
"lb", "lb-LU", "lg", "lg-UG", "lkt", "lkt-US", "ln", "ln-AO",
"ln-CD", "ln-CF", "ln-CG", "lo", "lo-LA", "lrc", "lrc-IQ",
"lrc-IR", "lt", "lt-LT", "lu", "lu-CD", "luo", "luo-KE", "luy",
"luy-KE", "lv", "lv-LV", "mas", "mas-KE", "mas-TZ", "mer",
"mer-KE", "mfe", "mfe-MU", "mg", "mg-MG", "mgh", "mgh-MZ", "mgo",
"mgo-CM", "mk", "mk-MK", "ml", "ml-IN", "mn", "mn-MN", "mr",
"mr-IN", "ms", "ms-BN", "ms-MY", "ms-SG", "mt", "mt-MT", "mua",
"mua-CM", "my", "my-MM", "mzn", "mzn-IR", "naq", "naq-NA", "nb",
"nb-NO", "nb-SJ", "nd", "nd-ZW", "nds", "nds-DE", "nds-NL", "ne",
"ne-IN", "ne-NP", "nl", "nl-AW", "nl-BE", "nl-BQ", "nl-CW",
"nl-NL", "nl-SR", "nl-SX", "nmg", "nmg-CM", "nn", "nn-NO", "nnh",
"nnh-CM", "nus", "nus-SS", "nyn", "nyn-UG", "om", "om-ET",
"om-KE", "or", "or-IN", "os", "os-GE", "os-RU", "pa", "pa-Arab",
"pa-Arab-PK", "pa-Guru", "pa-Guru-IN", "pl", "pl-PL", "ps",
"ps-AF", "pt", "pt-AO", "pt-BR", "pt-CH", "pt-CV", "pt-GQ",
"pt-GW", "pt-LU", "pt-MO", "pt-MZ", "pt-PT", "pt-ST", "pt-TL",
"qu", "qu-BO", "qu-EC", "qu-PE", "rm", "rm-CH", "rn", "rn-BI",
"ro", "ro-MD", "ro-RO", "rof", "rof-TZ", "ru", "ru-BY", "ru-KG",
"ru-KZ", "ru-MD", "ru-RU", "ru-UA", "rw", "rw-RW", "rwk",
"rwk-TZ", "sah", "sah-RU", "saq", "saq-KE", "sbp", "sbp-TZ", "se",
"se-FI", "se-NO", "se-SE", "seh", "seh-MZ", "ses", "ses-ML", "sg",
"sg-CF", "shi", "shi-Latn", "shi-Latn-MA", "shi-Tfng",
"shi-Tfng-MA", "si", "si-LK", "sk", "sk-SK", "sl", "sl-SI", "smn",
"smn-FI", "sn", "sn-ZW", "so", "so-DJ", "so-ET", "so-KE", "so-SO",
"sq", "sq-AL", "sq-MK", "sq-XK", "sr", "sr-Cyrl", "sr-Cyrl-BA",
"sr-Cyrl-ME", "sr-Cyrl-RS", "sr-Cyrl-XK", "sr-Latn", "sr-Latn-BA",
"sr-Latn-ME", "sr-Latn-RS", "sr-Latn-XK", "sv", "sv-AX", "sv-FI",
"sv-SE", "sw", "sw-CD", "sw-KE", "sw-TZ", "sw-UG", "ta", "ta-IN",
"ta-LK", "ta-MY", "ta-SG", "te", "te-IN", "teo", "teo-KE",
"teo-UG", "tg", "tg-TJ", "th", "th-TH", "ti", "ti-ER", "ti-ET",
"to", "to-TO", "tr", "tr-CY", "tr-TR", "tt", "tt-RU", "twq",
"twq-NE", "tzm", "tzm-MA", "ug", "ug-CN", "uk", "uk-UA", "ur",
"ur-IN", "ur-PK", "uz", "uz-Arab", "uz-Arab-AF", "uz-Cyrl",
"uz-Cyrl-UZ", "uz-Latn", "uz-Latn-UZ", "vai", "vai-Latn",
"vai-Latn-LR", "vai-Vaii", "vai-Vaii-LR", "vi", "vi-VN", "vun",
"vun-TZ", "wae", "wae-CH", "wo", "wo-SN", "xog", "xog-UG", "yav",
"yav-CM", "yi", "yi-001", "yo", "yo-BJ", "yo-NG", "yue",
"yue-Hans", "yue-Hans-CN", "yue-Hant", "yue-Hant-HK", "zgh",
"zgh-MA", "zh", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hans-CN", "zh-Hans-HK",
"zh-Hans-MO", "zh-Hans-SG", "zh-Hant", "zh-Hant-HK", "zh-Hant-MO",
"zh-Hant-TW", "zu", "zu-ZA"];
```

Comment: Careful if you are just fast copying. It's just a summarized list of the possible values. A most accurately answer is from @Clement Herreman. For example, I live in Catalonia (Spain) and my result is ca_ES. I found they have an API which returns a JSON with all the codes for copying and pasting. https://www.localeplanet.com/api/codelist.json

Comment: @Raikish The link you provided seems also not accurate. it doesn't include `zh-CN`, which is the result from Chrome 108 in China Mainland.

Comment: @lyh543 I don't know if it is exactly the same, but I think it is the called zh-Hans-CN

Comment: @Raikish `zh-Hans-CN` is more specific, but my Chrome doesn't return this string.

Comment: take care this list is outdated! "it-IT" is also missing

Answer (score 5):

If anyone also needs the name of the language for user selection (created from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) using query selector so it's accurate):

```
[
    ['Abkhazian', 'ab'],
    ['Afar', 'aa'],
    ['Afrikaans', 'af'],
    ['Akan', 'ak'],
    ['Albanian', 'sq'],
    ['Amharic', 'am'],
    ['Arabic', 'ar'],
    ['Aragonese', 'an'],
    ['Armenian', 'hy'],
    ['Assamese', 'as'],
    ['Avaric', 'av'],
    ['Avestan', 'ae'],
    ['Aymara', 'ay'],
    ['Azerbaijani', 'az'],
    ['Bambara', 'bm'],
    ['Bashkir', 'ba'],
    ['Basque', 'eu'],
    ['Belarusian', 'be'],
    ['Bengali (Bangla)', 'bn'],
    ['Bihari', 'bh'],
    ['Bislama', 'bi'],
    ['Bosnian', 'bs'],
    ['Breton', 'br'],
    ['Bulgarian', 'bg'],
    ['Burmese', 'my'],
    ['Catalan', 'ca'],
    ['Chamorro', 'ch'],
    ['Chechen', 'ce'],
    ['Chichewa, Chewa, Nyanja', 'ny'],
    ['Chinese', 'zh'],
    ['Chinese (Simplified)', 'zh-Hans'],
    ['Chinese (Traditional)', 'zh-Hant'],
    ['Chuvash', 'cv'],
    ['Cornish', 'kw'],
    ['Corsican', 'co'],
    ['Cree', 'cr'],
    ['Croatian', 'hr'],
    ['Czech', 'cs'],
    ['Danish', 'da'],
    ['Divehi, Dhivehi, Maldivian', 'dv'],
    ['Dutch', 'nl'],
    ['Dzongkha', 'dz'],
    ['English', 'en'],
    ['Esperanto', 'eo'],
    ['Estonian', 'et'],
    ['Ewe', 'ee'],
    ['Faroese', 'fo'],
    ['Fijian', 'fj'],
    ['Finnish', 'fi'],
    ['French', 'fr'],
    ['Fula, Fulah, Pulaar, Pular', 'ff'],
    ['Galician', 'gl'],
    ['Gaelic (Scottish)', 'gd'],
    ['Gaelic (Manx)', 'gv'],
    ['Georgian', 'ka'],
    ['German', 'de'],
    ['Greek', 'el'],
    ['Greenlandic', 'kl'],
    ['Guarani', 'gn'],
    ['Gujarati', 'gu'],
    ['Haitian Creole', 'ht'],
    ['Hausa', 'ha'],
    ['Hebrew', 'he'],
    ['Herero', 'hz'],
    ['Hindi', 'hi'],
    ['Hiri Motu', 'ho'],
    ['Hungarian', 'hu'],
    ['Icelandic', 'is'],
    ['Ido', 'io'],
    ['Igbo', 'ig'],
    ['Indonesian', 'id, in'],
    ['Interlingua', 'ia'],
    ['Interlingue', 'ie'],
    ['Inuktitut', 'iu'],
    ['Inupiak', 'ik'],
    ['Irish', 'ga'],
    ['Italian', 'it'],
    ['Japanese', 'ja'],
    ['Javanese', 'jv'],
    ['Kalaallisut, Greenlandic', 'kl'],
    ['Kannada', 'kn'],
    ['Kanuri', 'kr'],
    ['Kashmiri', 'ks'],
    ['Kazakh', 'kk'],
    ['Khmer', 'km'],
    ['Kikuyu', 'ki'],
    ['Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)', 'rw'],
    ['Kirundi', 'rn'],
    ['Kyrgyz', 'ky'],
    ['Komi', 'kv'],
    ['Kongo', 'kg'],
    ['Korean', 'ko'],
    ['Kurdish', 'ku'],
    ['Kwanyama', 'kj'],
    ['Lao', 'lo'],
    ['Latin', 'la'],
    ['Latvian (Lettish)', 'lv'],
    ['Limburgish ( Limburger)', 'li'],
    ['Lingala', 'ln'],
    ['Lithuanian', 'lt'],
    ['Luga-Katanga', 'lu'],
    ['Luganda, Ganda', 'lg'],
    ['Luxembourgish', 'lb'],
    ['Manx', 'gv'],
    ['Macedonian', 'mk'],
    ['Malagasy', 'mg'],
    ['Malay', 'ms'],
    ['Malayalam', 'ml'],
    ['Maltese', 'mt'],
    ['Maori', 'mi'],
    ['Marathi', 'mr'],
    ['Marshallese', 'mh'],
    ['Moldavian', 'mo'],
    ['Mongolian', 'mn'],
    ['Nauru', 'na'],
    ['Navajo', 'nv'],
    ['Ndonga', 'ng'],
    ['Northern Ndebele', 'nd'],
    ['Nepali', 'ne'],
    ['Norwegian', 'no'],
    ['Norwegian bokmål', 'nb'],
    ['Norwegian nynorsk', 'nn'],
    ['Nuosu', 'ii'],
    ['Occitan', 'oc'],
    ['Ojibwe', 'oj'],
    ['Old Church Slavonic, Old Bulgarian', 'cu'],
    ['Oriya', 'or'],
    ['Oromo (Afaan Oromo)', 'om'],
    ['Ossetian', 'os'],
    ['Pāli', 'pi'],
    ['Pashto, Pushto', 'ps'],
    ['Persian (Farsi)', 'fa'],
    ['Polish', 'pl'],
    ['Portuguese', 'pt'],
    ['Punjabi (Eastern)', 'pa'],
    ['Quechua', 'qu'],
    ['Romansh', 'rm'],
    ['Romanian', 'ro'],
    ['Russian', 'ru'],
    ['Sami', 'se'],
    ['Samoan', 'sm'],
    ['Sango', 'sg'],
    ['Sanskrit', 'sa'],
    ['Serbian', 'sr'],
    ['Serbo-Croatian', 'sh'],
    ['Sesotho', 'st'],
    ['Setswana', 'tn'],
    ['Shona', 'sn'],
    ['Sichuan Yi', 'ii'],
    ['Sindhi', 'sd'],
    ['Sinhalese', 'si'],
    ['Siswati', 'ss'],
    ['Slovak', 'sk'],
    ['Slovenian', 'sl'],
    ['Somali', 'so'],
    ['Southern Ndebele', 'nr'],
    ['Spanish', 'es'],
    ['Sundanese', 'su'],
    ['Swahili (Kiswahili)', 'sw'],
    ['Swati', 'ss'],
    ['Swedish', 'sv'],
    ['Tagalog', 'tl'],
    ['Tahitian', 'ty'],
    ['Tajik', 'tg'],
    ['Tamil', 'ta'],
    ['Tatar', 'tt'],
    ['Telugu', 'te'],
    ['Thai', 'th'],
    ['Tibetan', 'bo'],
    ['Tigrinya', 'ti'],
    ['Tonga', 'to'],
    ['Tsonga', 'ts'],
    ['Turkish', 'tr'],
    ['Turkmen', 'tk'],
    ['Twi', 'tw'],
    ['Uyghur', 'ug'],
    ['Ukrainian', 'uk'],
    ['Urdu', 'ur'],
    ['Uzbek', 'uz'],
    ['Venda', 've'],
    ['Vietnamese', 'vi'],
    ['Volapük', 'vo'],
    ['Wallon', 'wa'],
    ['Welsh', 'cy'],
    ['Wolof', 'wo'],
    ['Western Frisian', 'fy'],
    ['Xhosa', 'xh'],
    ['Yiddish', 'yi, ji'],
    ['Yoruba', 'yo'],
    ['Zhuang, Chuang', 'za'],
    ['Zulu', 'zu'],
]
```

Answer (score 4):

In some case, `navigator.language` can return something like "sr-Latn-RS"

According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) `navigator.language` can return every value valid in BCP-47: https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47

Answer (score 3):

Or an array of objects with "name" and "code" keys

```
[
  { code: 'ab', name: 'Abkhazian' },
  { code: 'aa', name: 'Afar' },
  { code: 'af', name: 'Afrikaans' },
  { code: 'ak', name: 'Akan' },
  { code: 'sq', name: 'Albanian' },
  { code: 'am', name: 'Amharic' },
  { code: 'ar', name: 'Arabic' },
  { code: 'an', name: 'Aragonese' },
  { code: 'hy', name: 'Armenian' },
  { code: 'as', name: 'Assamese' },
  { code: 'av', name: 'Avaric' },
  { code: 'ae', name: 'Avestan' },
  { code: 'ay', name: 'Aymara' },
  { code: 'az', name: 'Azerbaijani' },
  { code: 'bm', name: 'Bambara' },
  { code: 'ba', name: 'Bashkir' },
  { code: 'eu', name: 'Basque' },
  { code: 'be', name: 'Belarusian' },
  { code: 'bn', name: 'Bengali (Bangla)' },
  { code: 'bh', name: 'Bihari' },
  { code: 'bi', name: 'Bislama' },
  { code: 'bs', name: 'Bosnian' },
  { code: 'br', name: 'Breton' },
  { code: 'bg', name: 'Bulgarian' },
  { code: 'my', name: 'Burmese' },
  { code: 'ca', name: 'Catalan' },
  { code: 'ch', name: 'Chamorro' },
  { code: 'ce', name: 'Chechen' },
  { code: 'ny', name: 'Chichewa, Chewa, Nyanja' },
  { code: 'zh', name: 'Chinese' },
  { code: 'zh-Hans', name: 'Chinese (Simplified)' },
  { code: 'zh-Hant', name: 'Chinese (Traditional)' },
  { code: 'cv', name: 'Chuvash' },
  { code: 'kw', name: 'Cornish' },
  { code: 'co', name: 'Corsican' },
  { code: 'cr', name: 'Cree' },
  { code: 'hr', name: 'Croatian' },
  { code: 'cs', name: 'Czech' },
  { code: 'da', name: 'Danish' },
  { code: 'dv', name: 'Divehi, Dhivehi, Maldivian' },
  { code: 'nl', name: 'Dutch' },
  { code: 'dz', name: 'Dzongkha' },
  { code: 'en', name: 'English' },
  { code: 'eo', name: 'Esperanto' },
  { code: 'et', name: 'Estonian' },
  { code: 'ee', name: 'Ewe' },
  { code: 'fo', name: 'Faroese' },
  { code: 'fj', name: 'Fijian' },
  { code: 'fi', name: 'Finnish' },
  { code: 'fr', name: 'French' },
  { code: 'ff', name: 'Fula, Fulah, Pulaar, Pular' },
  { code: 'gl', name: 'Galician' },
  { code: 'gd', name: 'Gaelic (Scottish)' },
  { code: 'gv', name: 'Gaelic (Manx)' },
  { code: 'ka', name: 'Georgian' },
  { code: 'de', name: 'German' },
  { code: 'el', name: 'Greek' },
  { code: 'kl', name: 'Greenlandic' },
  { code: 'gn', name: 'Guarani' },
  { code: 'gu', name: 'Gujarati' },
  { code: 'ht', name: 'Haitian Creole' },
  { code: 'ha', name: 'Hausa' },
  { code: 'he', name: 'Hebrew' },
  { code: 'hz', name: 'Herero' },
  { code: 'hi', name: 'Hindi' },
  { code: 'ho', name: 'Hiri Motu' },
  { code: 'hu', name: 'Hungarian' },
  { code: 'is', name: 'Icelandic' },
  { code: 'io', name: 'Ido' },
  { code: 'ig', name: 'Igbo' },
  { code: 'id, in', name: 'Indonesian' },
  { code: 'ia', name: 'Interlingua' },
  { code: 'ie', name: 'Interlingue' },
  { code: 'iu', name: 'Inuktitut' },
  { code: 'ik', name: 'Inupiak' },
  { code: 'ga', name: 'Irish' },
  { code: 'it', name: 'Italian' },
  { code: 'ja', name: 'Japanese' },
  { code: 'jv', name: 'Javanese' },
  { code: 'kl', name: 'Kalaallisut, Greenlandic' },
  { code: 'kn', name: 'Kannada' },
  { code: 'kr', name: 'Kanuri' },
  { code: 'ks', name: 'Kashmiri' },
  { code: 'kk', name: 'Kazakh' },
  { code: 'km', name: 'Khmer' },
  { code: 'ki', name: 'Kikuyu' },
  { code: 'rw', name: 'Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)' },
  { code: 'rn', name: 'Kirundi' },
  { code: 'ky', name: 'Kyrgyz' },
  { code: 'kv', name: 'Komi' },
  { code: 'kg', name: 'Kongo' },
  { code: 'ko', name: 'Korean' },
  { code: 'ku', name: 'Kurdish' },
  { code: 'kj', name: 'Kwanyama' },
  { code: 'lo', name: 'Lao' },
  { code: 'la', name: 'Latin' },
  { code: 'lv', name: 'Latvian (Lettish)' },
  { code: 'li', name: 'Limburgish ( Limburger)' },
  { code: 'ln', name: 'Lingala' },
  { code: 'lt', name: 'Lithuanian' },
  { code: 'lu', name: 'Luga-Katanga' },
  { code: 'lg', name: 'Luganda, Ganda' },
  { code: 'lb', name: 'Luxembourgish' },
  { code: 'gv', name: 'Manx' },
  { code: 'mk', name: 'Macedonian' },
  { code: 'mg', name: 'Malagasy' },
  { code: 'ms', name: 'Malay' },
  { code: 'ml', name: 'Malayalam' },
  { code: 'mt', name: 'Maltese' },
  { code: 'mi', name: 'Maori' },
  { code: 'mr', name: 'Marathi' },
  { code: 'mh', name: 'Marshallese' },
  { code: 'mo', name: 'Moldavian' },
  { code: 'mn', name: 'Mongolian' },
  { code: 'na', name: 'Nauru' },
  { code: 'nv', name: 'Navajo' },
  { code: 'ng', name: 'Ndonga' },
  { code: 'nd', name: 'Northern Ndebele' },
  { code: 'ne', name: 'Nepali' },
  { code: 'no', name: 'Norwegian' },
  { code: 'nb', name: 'Norwegian bokmål' },
  { code: 'nn', name: 'Norwegian nynorsk' },
  { code: 'ii', name: 'Nuosu' },
  { code: 'oc', name: 'Occitan' },
  { code: 'oj', name: 'Ojibwe' },
  { code: 'cu', name: 'Old Church Slavonic, Old Bulgarian' },
  { code: 'or', name: 'Oriya' },
  { code: 'om', name: 'Oromo (Afaan Oromo)' },
  { code: 'os', name: 'Ossetian' },
  { code: 'pi', name: 'Pāli' },
  { code: 'ps', name: 'Pashto, Pushto' },
  { code: 'fa', name: 'Persian (Farsi)' },
  { code: 'pl', name: 'Polish' },
  { code: 'pt', name: 'Portuguese' },
  { code: 'pa', name: 'Punjabi (Eastern)' },
  { code: 'qu', name: 'Quechua' },
  { code: 'rm', name: 'Romansh' },
  { code: 'ro', name: 'Romanian' },
  { code: 'ru', name: 'Russian' },
  { code: 'se', name: 'Sami' },
  { code: 'sm', name: 'Samoan' },
  { code: 'sg', name: 'Sango' },
  { code: 'sa', name: 'Sanskrit' },
  { code: 'sr', name: 'Serbian' },
  { code: 'sh', name: 'Serbo-Croatian' },
  { code: 'st', name: 'Sesotho' },
  { code: 'tn', name: 'Setswana' },
  { code: 'sn', name: 'Shona' },
  { code: 'ii', name: 'Sichuan Yi' },
  { code: 'sd', name: 'Sindhi' },
  { code: 'si', name: 'Sinhalese' },
  { code: 'ss', name: 'Siswati' },
  { code: 'sk', name: 'Slovak' },
  { code: 'sl', name: 'Slovenian' },
  { code: 'so', name: 'Somali' },
  { code: 'nr', name: 'Southern Ndebele' },
  { code: 'es', name: 'Spanish' },
  { code: 'su', name: 'Sundanese' },
  { code: 'sw', name: 'Swahili (Kiswahili)' },
  { code: 'ss', name: 'Swati' },
  { code: 'sv', name: 'Swedish' },
  { code: 'tl', name: 'Tagalog' },
  { code: 'ty', name: 'Tahitian' },
  { code: 'tg', name: 'Tajik' },
  { code: 'ta', name: 'Tamil' },
  { code: 'tt', name: 'Tatar' },
  { code: 'te', name: 'Telugu' },
  { code: 'th', name: 'Thai' },
  { code: 'bo', name: 'Tibetan' },
  { code: 'ti', name: 'Tigrinya' },
  { code: 'to', name: 'Tonga' },
  { code: 'ts', name: 'Tsonga' },
  { code: 'tr', name: 'Turkish' },
  { code: 'tk', name: 'Turkmen' },
  { code: 'tw', name: 'Twi' },
  { code: 'ug', name: 'Uyghur' },
  { code: 'uk', name: 'Ukrainian' },
  { code: 'ur', name: 'Urdu' },
  { code: 'uz', name: 'Uzbek' },
  { code: 've', name: 'Venda' },
  { code: 'vi', name: 'Vietnamese' },
  { code: 'vo', name: 'Volapük' },
  { code: 'wa', name: 'Wallon' },
  { code: 'cy', name: 'Welsh' },
  { code: 'wo', name: 'Wolof' },
  { code: 'fy', name: 'Western Frisian' },
  { code: 'xh', name: 'Xhosa' },
  { code: 'yi, ji', name: 'Yiddish' },
  { code: 'yo', name: 'Yoruba' },
  { code: 'za', name: 'Zhuang, Chuang' },
  { code: 'zu', name: 'Zulu' },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a json of commonly used locales:

```
{
  "locales": [
    {
      "name": "Afrikaans (South Africa)",
      "code": "af_ZA",
      "region": "South Africa"
    },
    {
      "name": "Albanian (Albania)",
      "code": "sq_AL",
      "region": "Albania"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Algeria)",
      "code": "ar_DZ",
      "region": "Algeria"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Bahrain)",
      "code": "ar_BH",
      "region": "Bahrain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Egypt)",
      "code": "ar_EG",
      "region": "Egypt"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Iraq)",
      "code": "ar_IQ",
      "region": "Iraq"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Jordan)",
      "code": "ar_JO",
      "region": "Jordan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Kuwait)",
      "code": "ar_KW",
      "region": "Kuwait"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Lebanon)",
      "code": "ar_LB",
      "region": "Lebanon"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Libya)",
      "code": "ar_LY",
      "region": "Libya"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Morocco)",
      "code": "ar_MA",
      "region": "Morocco"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Oman)",
      "code": "ar_OM",
      "region": "Oman"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Qatar)",
      "code": "ar_QA",
      "region": "Qatar"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Saudi Arabia)",
      "code": "ar_SA",
      "region": "Saudi Arabia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Sudan)",
      "code": "ar_SD",
      "region": "Sudan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Syria)",
      "code": "ar_SY",
      "region": "Syria"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Tunisia)",
      "code": "ar_TN",
      "region": "Tunisia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (United Arab Emirates)",
      "code": "ar_AE",
      "region": "United Arab Emirates"
    },
    {
      "name": "Arabic (Yemen)",
      "code": "ar_YE",
      "region": "Yemen"
    },
    {
      "name": "Armenian (Armenia)",
      "code": "hy_AM",
      "region": "Armenia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Assamese (India)",
      "code": "as_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Azerbaijani (Azerbaijan)",
      "code": "az_AZ",
      "region": "Azerbaijan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bengali (Bangladesh)",
      "code": "bn_BD",
      "region": "Bangladesh"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bengali (India)",
      "code": "bn_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bosnian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)",
      "code": "bs_BA",
      "region": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bulgarian (Bulgaria)",
      "code": "bg_BG",
      "region": "Bulgaria"
    },
    {
      "name": "Catalan (Spain)",
      "code": "ca_ES",
      "region": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Chinese (Simplified Han)",
      "code": "zh_Hans",
      "region": "China"
    },
    {
      "name": "Chinese (Traditional Han)",
      "code": "zh_Hant",
      "region": "Taiwan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Croatian (Croatia)",
      "code": "hr_HR",
      "region": "Croatia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Czech (Czech Republic)",
      "code": "cs_CZ",
      "region": "Czech Republic"
    },
    {
      "name": "Danish (Denmark)",
      "code": "da_DK",
      "region": "Denmark"
    },
    {
      "name": "Divehi (Maldives)",
      "code": "dv_MV",
      "region": "Maldives"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dutch (Belgium)",
      "code": "nl_BE",
      "region": "Belgium"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dutch (Netherlands)",
      "code": "nl_NL",
      "region": "Netherlands"
    },
    {
      "name": "English (Australia)",
      "code": "en_AU",
      "region": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "name": "English (Canada)",
      "code": "en_CA",
      "region": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "name": "English (India)",
      "code": "en_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "English (Ireland)",
      "code": "en_IE",
      "region": "Ireland"
    },
    {
      "name": "English (New Zealand)",
      "code": "en_NZ",
      "region": "New Zealand"
    },
    {
      "name": "English (South Africa)",
      "code": "en_ZA",
      "region": "South Africa"
    },
    {
      "name": "English (Zimbabwe)",
      "code": "en_ZW",
      "region": "Zimbabwe"
    },
    {
      "name": "Estonian (Estonia)",
      "code": "et_EE",
      "region": "Estonia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Faroese (Faroe Islands)",
      "code": "fo_FO",
      "region": "Faroe Islands"
    },
    {
      "name": "Filipino (Philippines)",
      "code": "fil_PH",
      "region": "Philippines"
    },
    {
      "name": "Finnish (Finland)",
      "code": "fi_FI",
      "region": "Finland"
    },
    {
      "name": "French (Belgium)",
      "code": "fr_BE",
      "region": "Belgium"
    },
    {
      "name": "French (Canada)",
      "code": "fr_CA",
      "region": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "name": "French (Switzerland)",
      "code": "fr_CH",
      "region": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "name": "Galician (Spain)",
      "code": "gl_ES",
      "region": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Georgian (Georgia)",
      "code": "ka_GE",
      "region": "Georgia"
    },
    {
      "name": "German (Austria)",
      "code": "de_AT",
      "region": "Austria"
    },
    {
      "name": "German (Belgium)",
      "code": "de_BE",
      "region": "Belgium"
    },
    {
      "name": "German (Luxembourg)",
      "code": "de_LU",
      "region": "Luxembourg"
    },
    {
      "name": "German (Switzerland)",
      "code": "de_CH",
      "region": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "name": "Greek (Cyprus)",
      "code": "el_CY",
      "region": "Cyprus"
    },
    {
      "name": "Greek (Greece)",
      "code": "el_GR",
      "region": "Greece"
    },
    {
      "name": "Gujarati (India)",
      "code": "gu_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hebrew (Israel)",
      "code": "he_IL",
      "region": "Israel"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hindi (India)",
      "code": "hi_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hungarian (Hungary)",
      "code": "hu_HU",
      "region": "Hungary"
    },
    {
      "name": "Icelandic (Iceland)",
      "code": "is_IS",
      "region": "Iceland"
    },
    {
      "name": "Indonesian (Indonesia)",
      "code": "id_ID",
      "region": "Indonesia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Italian (Italy)",
      "code": "it_IT",
      "region": "Italy"
    },
    {
      "name": "Italian (Switzerland)",
      "code": "it_CH",
      "region": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "name": "Japanese (Japan)",
      "code": "ja_JP",
      "region": "Japan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kannada (India)",
      "code": "kn_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kazakh (Kazakhstan)",
      "code": "kk_KZ",
      "region": "Kazakhstan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Khmer (Cambodia)",
      "code": "km_KH",
      "region": "Cambodia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Korean (South Korea)",
      "code": "ko_KR",
      "region": "South Korea"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kurdish (Iraq)",
      "code": "ku_IQ",
      "region": "Iraq"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan)",
      "code": "ky_KG",
      "region": "Kyrgyzstan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Lao (Laos)",
      "code": "lo_LA",
      "region": "Laos"
    },
    {
      "name": "Latvian (Latvia)",
      "code": "lv_LV",
      "region": "Latvia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Lithuanian (Lithuania)",
      "code": "lt_LT",
      "region": "Lithuania"
    },
    {
      "name": "Macedonian (North Macedonia)",
      "code": "mk_MK",
      "region": "North Macedonia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Malay (Brunei)",
      "code": "ms_BN",
      "region": "Brunei"
    },
    {
      "name": "Malay (Malaysia)",
      "code": "ms_MY",
      "region": "Malaysia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Malayalam (India)",
      "code": "ml_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Maltese (Malta)",
      "code": "mt_MT",
      "region": "Malta"
    },
    {
      "name": "Marathi (India)",
      "code": "mr_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mongolian (Mongolia)",
      "code": "mn_MN",
      "region": "Mongolia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Nepali (Nepal)",
      "code": "ne_NP",
      "region": "Nepal"
    },
    {
      "name": "Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)",
      "code": "nb_NO",
      "region": "Norway"
    },
    {
      "name": "Oriya (India)",
      "code": "or_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pashto (Afghanistan)",
      "code": "ps_AF",
      "region": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Persian (Iran)",
      "code": "fa_IR",
      "region": "Iran"
    },
    {
      "name": "Polish (Poland)",
      "code": "pl_PL",
      "region": "Poland"
    },
    {
      "name": "Portuguese (Brazil)",
      "code": "pt_BR",
      "region": "Brazil"
    },
    {
      "name": "Portuguese (Portugal)",
      "code": "pt_PT",
      "region": "Portugal"
    },
    {
      "name": "Punjabi (India)",
      "code": "pa_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Romanian (Romania)",
      "code": "ro_RO",
      "region": "Romania"
    },
    {
      "name": "Russian (Russia)",
      "code": "ru_RU",
      "region": "Russia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sanskrit (India)",
      "code": "sa_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Serbian (Serbia)",
      "code": "sr_RS",
      "region": "Serbia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sinhala (Sri Lanka)",
      "code": "si_LK",
      "region": "Sri Lanka"
    },
    {
      "name": "Slovak (Slovakia)",
      "code": "sk_SK",
      "region": "Slovakia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Slovenian (Slovenia)",
      "code": "sl_SI",
      "region": "Slovenia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Argentina)",
      "code": "es_AR",
      "region": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Bolivia)",
      "code": "es_BO",
      "region": "Bolivia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Chile)",
      "code": "es_CL",
      "region": "Chile"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Colombia)",
      "code": "es_CO",
      "region": "Colombia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Costa Rica)",
      "code": "es_CR",
      "region": "Costa Rica"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Dominican Republic)",
      "code": "es_DO",
      "region": "Dominican Republic"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Ecuador)",
      "code": "es_EC",
      "region": "Ecuador"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (El Salvador)",
      "code": "es_SV",
      "region": "El Salvador"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Guatemala)",
      "code": "es_GT",
      "region": "Guatemala"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Honduras)",
      "code": "es_HN",
      "region": "Honduras"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Mexico)",
      "code": "es_MX",
      "region": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Nicaragua)",
      "code": "es_NI",
      "region": "Nicaragua"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Panama)",
      "code": "es_PA",
      "region": "Panama"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Paraguay)",
      "code": "es_PY",
      "region": "Paraguay"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Peru)",
      "code": "es_PE",
      "region": "Peru"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Puerto Rico)",
      "code": "es_PR",
      "region": "Puerto Rico"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Spain)",
      "code": "es_ES",
      "region": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (United States)",
      "code": "es_US",
      "region": "United States"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Uruguay)",
      "code": "es_UY",
      "region": "Uruguay"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spanish (Venezuela)",
      "code": "es_VE",
      "region": "Venezuela"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sundanese (Indonesia)",
      "code": "su_ID",
      "region": "Indonesia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Swahili (Kenya)",
      "code": "sw_KE",
      "region": "Kenya"
    },
    {
      "name": "Swedish (Finland)",
      "code": "sv_FI",
      "region": "Finland"
    },
    {
      "name": "Swedish (Sweden)",
      "code": "sv_SE",
      "region": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tajik (Tajikistan)",
      "code": "tg_TJ",
      "region": "Tajikistan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tamil (India)",
      "code": "ta_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tatar (Russia)",
      "code": "tt_RU",
      "region": "Russia"
    },
    {
      "name": "Telugu (India)",
      "code": "te_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Thai (Thailand)",
      "code": "th_TH",
      "region": "Thailand"
    },
    {
      "name": "Turkish (Turkey)",
      "code": "tr_TR",
      "region": "Turkey"
    },
    {
      "name": "Turkmen (Turkmenistan)",
      "code": "tk_TM",
      "region": "Turkmenistan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ukrainian (Ukraine)",
      "code": "uk_UA",
      "region": "Ukraine"
    },
    {
      "name": "Urdu (India)",
      "code": "ur_IN",
      "region": "India"
    },
    {
      "name": "Urdu (Pakistan)",
      "code": "ur_PK",
      "region": "Pakistan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Uyghur (China)",
      "code": "ug_CN",
      "region": "China"
    },
    {
      "name": "Uzbek (Uzbekistan)",
      "code": "uz_UZ",
      "region": "Uzbekistan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vietnamese (Vietnam)",
      "code": "vi_VN",
      "region": "Vietnam"
    },
    {
      "name": "Welsh (United Kingdom)",
      "code": "cy_GB",
      "region": "United Kingdom"
    },
    {
      "name": "Xhosa (South Africa)",
      "code": "xh_ZA",
      "region": "South Africa"
    },
    {
      "name": "Yiddish (World)",
      "code": "yi",
      "region": "World"
    },
    {
      "name": "Yoruba (Nigeria)",
      "code": "yo_NG",
      "region": "Nigeria"
    },
    {
      "name": "Zulu (South Africa)",
      "code": "zu_ZA",
      "region": "South Africa"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you need an enum of languages without locale in typescript or plaint object in javascript for copy-paste purposes

```
export enum ISOLanguages {
  AF = 'af',
  SQ = 'sq',
  AR = 'ar',
  EU = 'eu',
  BG = 'bg',
  BE = 'be',
  CA = 'ca',
  ZH = 'zh',
  HR = 'hr',
  CS = 'cs',
  DA = 'da',
  NL = 'nl',
  EN = 'en',
  ET = 'et',
  FO = 'fo',
  FA = 'fa',
  FI = 'fi',
  FR = 'fr',
  GD = 'gd',
  DE = 'de',
  EL = 'el',
  HE = 'he',
  HI = 'hi',
  HU = 'hu',
  IS = 'is',
  ID = 'id',
  IT = 'it',
  JA = 'ja',
  KO = 'ko',
  LV = 'lv',
  LT = 'lt',
  MK = 'mk',
  MT = 'mt',
  NO = 'no',
  PL = 'pl',
  PT = 'pt',
  RM = 'rm',
  RO = 'ro',
  RU = 'ru',
  SZ = 'sz',
  SR = 'sr',
  SK = 'sk',
  SL = 'sl',
  SB = 'sb',
  ES = 'es',
  SX = 'sx',
  SV = 'sv',
  TH = 'th',
  TS = 'ts',
  TN = 'tn',
  TR = 'tr',
  UK = 'uk',
  UR = 'ur',
  VE = 've',
  VI = 'vi',
  XH = 'xh',
  JI = 'ji',
  ZU = 'zu',
}
```