# Javascript : list all browser languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown in my html UI, which has to be populated with list of all browser languages/input installed languages(not the the first language).

I was able to get the first language(i.e. en-us), but i have zh-CN chinese pack also installed for my OS.i used below code which is giving me only first language from list:

```
 <select class="sideBtn" size="1" id="LANGUAGE_LISTBOX" accesskey="L" title="Select Languages:" onChange="LanguageChange();">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var language = navigator.browserLanguage;
        document.write('<option value="' + language + '">' + language + '</option>');
            </script>
  </select>
```

I have glanced below article, but navigator.Languages not working in IE.
http://gu.illau.me/posts/the-problem-of-user-language-lists-in-javascript/
Can some one help m eon this??

Deepthi

Comment: if language is an array of languages, you should loop through it (foreach) and put the document.write inside that loop.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580876/navigator-language-list-of-all-languages/36042028#36042028

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the moment. `navigator.languages` is only implemented in Firefox at this time as you can see from the relevant [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage.languages), and it only lists the user's preferred languages as configured in Firefox settings, not the languages installed in OS. There is no alternative way to get to such information from JavaScript.